# How to follow symlinks in visual studio and cmake in windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, symlink

When building a c++ project in Visual Studio (2008 in this case), the compiler checks for each source file if there is already an .obj file and only rebuilds the .obj file if any of the input files, which are headers and a source file, are newer than the .obj.

This fails if any of the input files are symlinks because Visual Studio doesnt follow symlinks and only looks at the change date of the symlink itself.

E.g. `Test.cpp (symlink 15:30)` points to `../Common/Source/Test.cpp (changed 16:38)` should produce 
`Test.obj (changed 15:31)`. Unfortunately VS wont follow symlinks and doesnt see that the original file was updated.

GNU make and gcc can follow symlinks, is there an equivalent in Visual Studio or is there another option for Windows? The change date of a symlink should also reflect the change date of the original file, IMHO, since a symlink cant be changed in Windows anyway.